# Excel Worksheet.Change Target.Count > 1 - How do I know if the count applies to rows or columns

Tags: excel, vba

on a Worksheet.Change, the user may be pasting to more than one row or column.  In the Target Range, it gives the first row (Target.row) and the first column (Target.column) and the number of cells affected (Target.Count).  HOW do I know whether the count applies to the number of rows or columns or both?

Michelle

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim CurrentColumn, CurrentRow, NumRows, NumCols As Integer

    CurrentColumn = target.Column
    CurrentRow = target.Row

    
    If target.Count > 1 Then
        'determine if they pasted more than one row or more than one column

        ' NumRows = target.Count    or   NumCols = target.Count  Could be either or both?????  
        'How do I tell if they pasted to multiple rows or multiple columns?
    
    End If
```

Comment: `target.rows.count` and `target.columns.count`

Comment: So simple.  How did I miss this.  Thank you!